# Evaluate a piecewise linear function

Tags: algorithm, search

For a given piecewise linear function, what is the best way to store it in memory so that it can be evaluated quickly?

I was thinking of storing the breakpoints in an array and searching for the right segment by binary search. Is there any better approach?

Comment: Here's a crazy thought: how about as a *function*? You haven't specified any language or framework, but this would be very elegant on Python.

Comment: binary search on breakpoints sounds good to me. Maybe storing the last found location and try with this first since it might be likely that the next invocation of the function is in the neighborhood.